# Query that returns date of first and last record for each day within a d

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that records vehicle locations and I wish to query this to get the first and the last record for each vehicle for each day in a date range. The table looks like:

```
Registration Latitude Longitude dateOfRecord
A1 XBO        123.066 1.456     2019-08-01 00:04:19.000
A1 XBO        128.066 1.436     2019-08-01 22:04:19.000
A1 XBO        118.066 1.456      2019-08-01 23:45:00.000
```

There are multiple vehicles with three weeks worth of data being held in the table 100,000 records this is written to an archive every night which leaves a 21 days of records which I wish to query. With my sample I would like to get:

```
Reg     Day     StartTime StartLat  StartLong EndTime  EndLat EndLong
A2 XBO  01-08-19 00:04     123.066   1.456     23:45   118.066 1.456
```

I have an existing query that gets the most recent records but this can't be used for my requirements as it uses the MAX(ID) within the query and I don't believe that you can mix both MAX and MIN in the same query. I could use this as the basis of a table in a stored procedure and then loop through the records and query each to get the first record in the date range but this would be a very resource greedy process! I have included this purely to show what I already have:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT m.Registration, m.Location, m.dateoffix, 
m.Latitude, m.Longitude, MAX(m.ID) AS ID
FROM            dbo.GPSPositions AS m 
                     INNER JOIN
                         (SELECT        Registration AS vr, 
MAX(CONVERT(datetime, dateoffix, 103)) AS tdate
                           FROM            dbo.GPSPositions
                           GROUP BY Registration) AS s ON m.Registration = 
s.vr AND CONVERT(datetime, m.dateoffix, 103) = s.tdate
GROUP BY m.Registration, m.Location, m.dateoffix, m.Latitude, m.Longitude                           
ORDER BY m.Registration
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you think `TOP (100) PERCENT` does?

Comment: It should not be there!

Comment: Hint - rownumber where you partition by the date portion of dateOfRecord in both ascending and descending order. Another hint - you will need a list of all dates within your date period if you want to see all dates in your resultset (as opposed to just those present within the selected rows). If only we had a name for something that contained all dates (hint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix Max and Min in the same query.

```
with firstLast (Registration, firstRec, lastRec) as
(
select [Registration], min([dateOfRecord]) as firstRec, max(dateOfRecord) as lastRec
from GPSPositions
group by [Registration], cast(dateOfRecord as Date)
)
select 
   fl.Registration as Reg,
   Cast(gpsF.dateOfRecord as Date) as [Day],
   Cast(gpsF.dateOfRecord as Time) as [StartTime],
   gpsF.Latitude as StartLat,
   gpsF.Longitude as StartLon,
   Cast(gpsL.dateOfRecord as Time) as [EndTime],
   gpsL.Latitude as EndLat,
   gpsL.Longitude as EndLon
from firstLast fl
inner join GPSPositions gpsF on gpsF.Registration = fl.Registration and gpsF.dateOfRecord = fl.firstRec
inner join GPSPositions gpsL on gpsL.Registration = fl.Registration and gpsL.dateOfRecord = fl.lastRec;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5d78514299cbac1f4da3c001d9c8250)

EDIT: If there could be entries for the same registration at the same time (ID is unique and increasing - ordered by dateOfRecord):

```
with firstLast (registration,firstRec, lastRec) as
(
select registration,min(id) as firstRec, max(id) as lastRec
from GPSPositions
group by [Registration], cast(dateOfRecord as Date)
)
select 
   fl.Registration as Reg,
   Cast(gpsF.dateOfRecord as Date) as [Day],
   Cast(gpsF.dateOfRecord as Time) as [StartTime],
   gpsF.Latitude as StartLat,
   gpsF.Longitude as StartLon,
   Cast(gpsL.dateOfRecord as Time) as [EndTime],
   gpsL.Latitude as EndLat,
   gpsL.Longitude as EndLon
from firstLast fl
inner join GPSPositions gpsF on gpsF.Id = fl.firstRec
inner join GPSPositions gpsL on gpsL.ID = fl.lastRec;
```

Comment: Hi Cetin, Thanks for taking the time to respond to my request for assistance. Again I adapted your query to the existing table the data types in the table are the same as the one created in your example but the grouping did not work correctly as all the records were generated!

Comment: @joebohen, I believe you made a mistake during adaption. You can check the DbFiddle demo link, and preferably give your adoption as a DBFiddle demo.

Comment: Hi Cetin,  I am not making any changes other than linking the select query in your code to the working table rather than generating a table.  The code remains exactly the same.

Comment: @joebohen, then it should work. I really would like to see the code that is failing (along with data) - in your select I see different field names

Comment: Hi Cetin,  Sorry that it has taken me so long to get back to you please see the code and records below:

Comment: @joebohen, np but I don't see them. Where is "below"?

Comment: Sorry I missed the fiddle!

Comment: @joebohen, for XBO50 there are 2 entries on the same time (end time). I assumed there wouldn't be any 2 entries occurring at the same time for the same registration. If there could be than the query should be based on Id. I will add that to my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `APPLY` operator and do something like:

```
DECLARE @t table
(
    Registration varchar(10)
    , Latitude decimal(6, 3)
    , Longitude decimal(6, 3)
    , dateOfRecord datetime
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('A1 XBO', 123.066, 1.456, '2019-08-01 00:04:19.000')
, ('A1 XBO', 128.066, 1.436, '2019-08-01 22:04:19.000')
, ('A1 XBO', 118.066, 1.456, '2019-08-01 23:45:00.000')

SELECT DISTINCT
    Registration Reg
    , CAST(dateOfRecord AS date) [Day]
    , T_MIN.[Time] StartTime
    , T_MIN.Latitude StartLat
    , T_MIN.Longitude StartLong
    , T_MAX.[Time] EndTime
    , T_MAX.Latitude EndLat
    , T_MAX.Longitude EndLong
FROM
    @t T
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            CAST(T_MIN.dateOfRecord AS time) [Time]
            , Latitude
            , Longitude
        FROM @t T_MIN
        WHERE
            T_MIN.Registration = T.Registration
            AND CAST(T_MIN.dateOfRecord AS date) =  CAST(T.dateOfRecord AS date)
        ORDER BY T_MIN.dateOfRecord
    ) T_MIN
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            CAST(T_MAX.dateOfRecord AS time) [Time]
            , Latitude
            , Longitude
        FROM @t T_MAX
        WHERE
            T_MAX.Registration = T.Registration
            AND CAST(T_MAX.dateOfRecord AS date) =  CAST(T.dateOfRecord AS date)
        ORDER BY T_MAX.dateOfRecord DESC
    ) T_MAX
```

**Edit**

Based on @SMor's comment, you could also try something like:

```
DECLARE @t table
(
    Registration varchar(10)
    , Latitude decimal(6, 3)
    , Longitude decimal(6, 3)
    , dateOfRecord datetime
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('A1 XBO', 123.066, 1.456, '2019-08-01 00:04:19.000')
, ('A1 XBO', 128.066, 1.436, '2019-08-01 22:04:19.000')
, ('A1 XBO', 118.066, 1.456, '2019-08-01 23:45:00.000')

SELECT
    Reg
    , [Day]
    , MIN([Time]) StartTime
    , MIN(Latitude) StartLat
    , MIN(Longitude) StartLong
    , MAX([Time]) EndTime
    , MAX(Latitude) EndLat
    , MAX(Longitude) EndLong
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Registration Reg
            , CAST(dateOfRecord AS date) [Day]
            , CAST(dateOfRecord AS time) [Time]
            , Latitude
            , Longitude
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Registration, CAST(dateOfRecord AS date) ORDER BY dateOfRecord) Mn
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Registration, CAST(dateOfRecord AS date) ORDER BY dateOfRecord DESC) Mx
        FROM @t T
    ) Q
WHERE
    Mn = 1
    OR Mx = 1
GROUP BY
    Reg
    , [Day]
```

Comment: Hi Chris,  Thanks for your reply, I attempted to convert your code to my working environment but because of the number of registrations and records (when I counted the records there was closer to 1,000,000) it took forever to run.

Comment: Is your table indexed?

Comment: Yes its Indexed as

Comment: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GPSPosition_dateofRecord]
    ON [dbo].[GPSPositions]([dateofRecord] ASC)
    INCLUDE([ID], [Registration], [Location], [Latitude], [Longitude], [VehID]);

Comment: Is the query using the index? I would probably try an index on Registration as well.

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer based on the comment from @SMor (it appears to have a better execution plan).

Comment: Thanks to you both for your contributions they were both excellent and did what I wanted to achieve I have selected Cetin's answer purely on the basis of performance.